# What are the requirements to upgrade office zones to the max level?

Tags: cities-skylines

A lot of my office zones seems to be on the cusp of reaching the third level, but it would never reach it. I placed fire stations, police stations, parks, and just about anything I could think of that an office would need. I also have a surplus of highly educated citizens, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

What are the requirements for office zones to reach their max level?

Comment: Do you have public transit in the area?

Comment: I think so yeah. I have multiple bus lines running through the office blocks that I have. I don't really want to spam them though, but it seems like that's the only way.

Comment: Yeah, rather than spamming a certain type, diversify. Maybe build a longer range metro system that brings people from the outlying areas into your office blocks, where they can then take the buses around to their specific destination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along with the "big" city services like education and fire, there are a few other things to check and to provide if you want your buildings to upgrade.

The first that I would suggest you look at is public transit. Any kind will do, buses, subways, trains, whatever.

The next thing to look at is your data overlays. What's the pollution like in the area? Noise? Upgrading the nearby streets to be tree-lined improves noise pollution and can make people happy.

As a general principle, anything that makes those little smiley faces pop up over the buildings is increasing their happiness and moving them towards upgrading.

Note that these work for any kind of building that can upgrade, including industry. Non-office industry once upgraded produces less pollution and employs higher educated citizens. Just noting this because its something that I see a lot of people neglect (Parks? In my industrial area?!).

Comment: One reason why I asked was if placing schools and hospitals near offices actually helped. And it did, at least a little, after much observation that I did. The same goes to factories.

Hospitals I can understand, but I dunno what offices and factories gain when I place elementary schools near them. Oh well, hopefully a mod can fix it or something.

Comment: Here is a reddit thread describing exactly what Offices need to reach level 3: http://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/2z5cp2/here_why_its_ridiculously_tedious_to_get_level_3/

Comment: @Frosteeze imagine being a single parent of a 7yo and a 9yo that cannot afford school-provided private transportation. Having an elementary school in close proximity to the workplace is an incredibly good thing to have.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same question, recently I've just found out that to get the Office to level 3 we will need to build all kinds of service available in game: police station, fire station, hospital etc... and parks as well, but usually even I have built all these around the office zone, it will still not get to max level, because probably the game developers want to make some difficulties for the players here.. but I figured out a good way is to spam bus stop and metro station around the zone, until the buildings get upgraded again :) hope this help :)